# Terminal Broken

Tags: gnome-terminal

I've been using Ubuntu for about a week now. I logged in today and launched the terminal I got presented a whole list of errors. I've tried to chsh but it won't recognise the command. Nor all other common ones.

Any ideas?

[image: http://oi48.tinypic.com/2zxt93d.jpg]

Extra info:
$PATH:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/jorden/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/jorden/android-sdk-l
```

Comment: What is your `$PATH`? Type `/bin/echo $PATH` and edit with the results.

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards `echo` is (also) a shell builtin, so even without an `echo` binary in the PATH, it's can be successfully invoked as just `echo`, In any case, lordqwerty, please do provide the information Jacob Johan Edwards has requested. Please also run `/bin/cat /home/jordan/.profile`, then `/bin/cat /home/jordan/.bash_profile`, then `/bin/cat /home/jordan/.bashrc` (and then copy all the text from the Terminal by selecting it and doing Edit > Copy, and paste it into your question when editing it). That should provide everything needed to identify the exact problem, and how best to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:${PATH}"
```

and then type the command you want to execute, for example:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If this works, you can add the line to your `.bashrc` inside your home directory to restore the correct `PATH`.

Comment: That code worked great thanks! I've launched nano as root to home/jorden/.bashrc and added the export to the top of the file. However when I log out I still get the same error as shown in the screenshot. Would the login.defs also need to be updated?

Comment: I run this and then done what Frantique said below and it worked great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Restore your `.bashrc` file with: `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/`, after that reboot, and enjoy!

Comment: When I done the above and then done this is worked. Thanks! :)